# Latest Common Month in a Country considering Category

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to create one  custom column(Latest Common Month in a Country) for flag in in Power query .On the basis Country ,Category ,Year , Month No. I am trying to find the Latest month in a country Flag.
The data looks like below:

[image]

I have tried with below  M Code but it is not considering the Category column:

```
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table20"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Country", type text}, {"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Month No", Int64.Type}}),

//Country List
countries = List.Distinct(Table.Column(#"Changed Type","Country")),

//Calculate full date
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "fullDate", each #date([Year],[Month No],1),type date),

//determine latest month flag by country
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"Country"}, {{"grouped", each _, type table [Country=nullable text, Year=nullable number, Month No=nullable number, fullDate=date]}, {"latest fullDate", each List.Max([fullDate]), type date}}),
#"Expanded grouped" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "grouped", {"Year", "Month No", "fullDate"}, {"Year", "Month No", "fullDate"}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded grouped", "Latest Month Flag", each if [latest fullDate] = [fullDate] then 1 else 0),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"latest fullDate"}),
```

Please help me to find the latest common month in each country considering Category

Comment: I'm not following your logic.  There doesn't seem to be a latest common month for some of the `country/category/date combinations`.  Wouldn't that be, for toothpaste `2019/10` because it is the only category/date combo present in all three countries?

Comment: Here 2019/10 toothpaste for country Aus is not latest year....2021/9 is latest...For one country I am trying to get the Latest date considering the Category column also..

Comment: I guess I don't understand when you write *latest **common** month* vs just *latest month* for a given country/category combination.  What is the difference in those phrases?  Extracting the latest month (or year/month) for a given country/category combination is just a matter of using the Max aggregation in the Table.Group dialog. A lot simpler than your previous problem. But clearly I'm missing something because in that case, Min for us/toothpaste would be 2019/10

Comment: Latest common I mean...latest month in the latest year,,,for deciding this I am not only considering Country  but also Cateogory name in the country.if Tooth paste latest  month is 08/2021 and sports 09/2021, then  for me latest common month for the country  is 08/2021

Comment: I see that for US, `2021 8` has both/all categories.  But what about UK?  For 2021, there are no months that have both `Toothpaste` and `Sports`.  So why choose one over the other?  Or why not choose `2020 12` which is the most recent date that has both?

Comment: Ideally there will be continuous month for Country and Category... I have updated UK data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restate/clarify what I think you want after the comments:

***The latest date in each country where all categories are present***

**Source**
[image]

*Algorithm explained in code comments*

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Country", type text}, {"Category", type text}, {"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Month No", Int64.Type}}),

//add index column to be able retain original order
   #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

//add a "real date" column: it will be useful when we determine latest common date
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Date", each #date([Year],[Month No],1)),

//create unique list of all categories for verification that all categories present
//  to determine latest common date
    allCat = List.Distinct(#"Added Custom2"[Category]),

//group by Country Year Month to assess if all categories present
    grp = Table.Group(#"Added Custom2",{"Country","Year","Month No"},
                {{"all", each _, type table[Category=text, Index=number]}}),

//if all categories present then mark it true
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(grp, "Common Month in Yr", 
        each List.RemoveMatchingItems(allCat,[all][Category])={}, type logical),

//expand. Then group by Country
//then filter each country to show only month/year where all categories are present (common)
    #"Expanded all" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "all", {"Category", "Index","Date"}, {"Category", "Index","Date"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Expanded all", {"Country"}, 
        {{"All", each _, type table [Country=nullable text, Year=nullable number, Month No=nullable number, Category=nullable text, Index=nullable number, Common Month in Yr=number]}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Max common year/month", each Table.SelectRows([All], each [Common Month in Yr])),
    
//For each grouped country with only the common month/years, return the latest
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Max Common", each List.Max([#"Max common year/month"][Date]), type date),

//Remove unneeded columns
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom3",{"Max common year/month"}),

//expand the table again
    #"Expanded All" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "All", 
        {"Year", "Month No", "Category", "Index"}, 
        {"Year", "Month No", "Category", "Index"}),

//sort back to original order; then remove the Index column
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded All",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"}),

//Mark latest common year/month by determining if it matches the latest date
//then remove unneeded column
    #"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Latest Common Month Country/Category/Year", each 
        if Date.Year([Max Common]) = [Year] and Date.Month([Max Common]) = [Month No] then 1 else 0),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom4",{"Max Common"})
in
    #"Removed Columns2"
```

**Results**
[image]

***Edit:*** Here's one way of combining the two:

**Source**
[image]

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Country", type text}, {"Category", type text}, {"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Month No", Int64.Type}}),

//add index column to be able retain original order
   #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

//add a "real date" column: it will be useful when we determine latest common date
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Date", each #date([Year],[Month No],1)),

//Create unique list of all countries
    allCountries = List.Distinct(#"Added Custom2"[Country]),

//group by Date to get last common month
    grpDate = Table.Group(#"Added Custom2","Date",
        {"allDate", each _, type table[Added Index=Int64.Type, Date=date, Category=text,Year=Int64.Type, Month No=Int64.Type ]}),

//mark each date that includes all countries
    CommonMonths= Table.AddColumn(grpDate,"Last Common Month", each List.RemoveMatchingItems(allCountries,[allDate][Country])={}, type logical),

//Determine maximum date that includes all the countries
    lastCommon = List.Max(Table.SelectRows(CommonMonths, each [Last Common Month])[Date]),
    
//Change the appropriate row to 1, else 0
    lastCommonMonth=
        Table.FromRecords(
            Table.TransformRows(CommonMonths, (row)=> 
                Record.TransformFields(row, {
                    {"Last Common Month", each if row[Date] = lastCommon then 1 else 0}
                }))),
//Expand this table and then calculate column including categories    
    expand = Table.ExpandTableColumn(lastCommonMonth,"allDate",
        {"Country","Category","Year","Month No","Index"},
        {"Country","Category","Year","Month No","Index"}),

//create unique list of all categories for verification that all categories present
//  to determine latest common date
    allCat = List.Distinct(#"Added Custom2"[Category]),

//group by Country Year Month to assess if all categories present
    grp = Table.Group(expand,{"Country","Year","Month No"},
                {{"all", each _, type table[Category=text, Index=Int64.Type, Last Common Month=Int64.Type]}}),

//if all categories present then mark it true
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(grp, "Common Month in Yr", 
        each List.RemoveMatchingItems(allCat,[all][Category])={}, type logical),

//expand. Then group by Country
//then filter each country to show only month/year where all categories are present (common)
    #"Expanded all" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "all", 
        {"Date","Category", "Index", "Last Common Month"}, 
        {"Date","Category", "Index", "Last Common Month"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Expanded all", {"Country"}, 
        {{"All", each _, type table [Country=nullable text, Year=nullable number, Month No=nullable number, Category=nullable text, Index=nullable number, Common Month in Yr=number]}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Max common year/month", each Table.SelectRows([All], each [Common Month in Yr])),
    
//For each grouped country with only the common month/years, return the latest
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Max Common", each List.Max([#"Max common year/month"][Date]), type date),

//Remove unneeded columns
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom3",{"Max common year/month"}),

//expand the table again
    #"Expanded All" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "All", 
        {"Year", "Month No", "Category", "Index","Last Common Month"}, 
        {"Year", "Month No", "Category", "Index","Last Common Month"}),

//sort back to original order; then remove the Index column
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded All",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"}),

//Mark latest common year/month by determining if it matches the latest date
//then remove unneeded column
    #"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Latest Common Month Country/Category/Year", each 
        if Date.Year([Max Common]) = [Year] and Date.Month([Max Common]) = [Month No] then 1 else 0),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom4",{"Max Common"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns2",{"Country", "Year", "Month No", "Category", "Latest Common Month Country/Category/Year", "Last Common Month"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

**Results**
[image]

Comment: Thanks Ron...this will work...but now only the issue for my second flag ....which was working fine bfore ..but with new logic it is not working...Could you please help me to write the M code for to find 'Latest common month flag availbale  in all the country without considering Category'.I  have updated my my data in the scree shot

Comment: @faisal You should be able to merge the two queries, but you'll have to do some manual editing. Also, in your updated example, why is `RUS 2021 8` not marked in the `Last common month including category` column.  It has all categories and `2021 8` is a common month.

Comment: Fixed the data error

Comment: @faisal See ***Edit*** for a method of combining the two.